# Does Stripe send data to webhooks when test payments are created?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm testing Stripe Connect integration. I've created a webhook endpoint for payment intent events and added it to the dashboard. From there I can successfully send an event to my endpoint and the endpoint receives that test data. 
However if I create or finalize a payment intent, no data is sent to the endpoint. 
I've searched the docs, but found no info if the Stripe webhooks are fully functional in test mode. The only relevant info that I found was [this paragraph from the docs](https://stripe.com/docs/testing):

> To test your integration, perform actions using the API (in test mode)
>   to send legitimate events to your endpoint. For instance, creating a
>   charge triggers the charge.succeeded event that contains the charge
>   data. You can then use the API to verify the resulting event data.

It implies that I'm supposed to receive `payment_intent.succeeded` or `payment_intent.created` events. But I don't.

Does test payments (or/and payment intents in particular) trigger webhooks in Stripe?

**COMMENT**

[The answer pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57595330/3298637) that there should be separate webhooks for connect events and the events for your platform. Initially all my webhooks were created [through the API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/webhook_endpoints/create#create_webhook_endpoint-connect) and intended for events from the connected accounts (with `connect: true` argument). I had a change in the initial specs for the app, and I missed that part indeed.

```
await StripeService.webhookEndpoints.create({
        connect: true,
        enabled_events: [
          "payment_intent.created",
          "payment_intent.payment_failed",
          "payment_intent.succeeded",
          "payment_intent.amount_capturable_updated"
        ],
        url: newPaymentIntentUrl,
      });
```

Comment: It should trigger the event regardless if it is in live or test mode and even regardless if you have a webhook endpoint created. 
Make sure your webhook are created in test mode if you are testing. Do you have a event id that is failing, you could paste it here

Comment: @wsw As I said, everything is functioning as it should, but the webhooks. Anyway, I found the correct answer. Thank you for your effort to help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Test Payments and objects in Stripe should send all webhooks of the types you select for a given endpoint, just as their live mode counterparts do.

Stripe has two different kinds of webhook endpoints, and this is a common area of confusion when using Connect:

- If you are creating and confirming these Payment Intents on `Connected Accounts` you will need to set up a **Connect webhook endpoint** https://stripe.com/docs/connect/webhooks
- If you are creating and confirming these Payment Intents on your `Platform Account` you will need to set up an **Account webhook endpoint** 
  https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/setup

You can define both types of webhook endpoints at https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/webhooks

[image]